# Variable dependent target in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a small project for testing and I want to link different implementations of a solution to test.

So, I create makefile that looks like this

```
CC=g++
FLAGS=-Wall -O2
CFLAGS=-c $(FLAGS)
I_PATH=implementation1.cpp

all: instance

instance: instance.cpp .implementation.o
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) instance.cpp .implementation.o -o $@

.implementation.o: $(I_PATH)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(I_PATH) -o $@

clean:
    -rm .implementation*
    -rm instance
```

Here, `I_PATH` is a path to solution implementation. And I want to test different solution passing different implementation via command line arguments: `make I_PATH=implementation2.cpp`.

But, because of all my implementations compiled to the same object file `.implementation.o`, `make` can't understand that something changes and doesn't rebuild project.

Of course, I can call `make clean` before run `make` for a specific implementation. But this increase build time (I can run tests for one implementation many times) and not very comfortable.

I can fix this makefile to something like this:

```
CC=g++
FLAGS=-Wall -O2
CFLAGS=-c $(FLAGS)
I_PATH=implementation1.cpp
C_PATH := $(shell echo -n $(I_PATH) | md5sum | awk '{print ".implementation_" substr($$1, 0, 10) ".o";}')

all: force instance

force_relink: 
    touch -c $(C_PATH)

instance: instance.cpp $(C_PATH)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) instance.cpp $(C_PATH) -o $@

$(C_PATH): $(I_PATH)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    -rm .implementation*
    -rm instance
```

Here I create `I_PATH` dependent object file(take hash of path to implementation) and in addition force re-linking `instance.cpp` with object file every time `make` runs.

But maybe there is some mechanism in `make` to fix this behavior? Or I can achieve the same goal with different approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it make more sense to give each compiled `.o` file a distinct name, and simply link to the compiled `.o` file you want?

```
instance: instance.cpp $(IMPL_O)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@  # propably no need to override default rule
```

Use `make IMPL_O=implementation2.o` to generate the example in your question.

This way, the name of each file truly reveals its identity, and you don't have to keep track of anything explicitly.

(Obviously, you could refactor the `.o` extension into the Makefile itself so you can just say `IMPL=implementation2` or whatever.)

Comment: Yes, this makes sense - simple and good solution.
Can you suggest another way of relinking or my approach acceptable?
Relinking needed for next situation: `make IMPL_O=i1.o`, `make IMPL_O=i2.o`, `make IMPL_O=i1.o` - in the third call make doesn't track changes and nothing will be rebuilt.

Comment: If simply removing the file and remaking it is not acceptable, something like what you did with the `md5sum` previously could be used to force remake if parameters change.

Comment: ... Or you could similarly give each compiled artefact a unique name which reflects which implementation it embedded.